# Importing Spark 2.0 Jars in Intellij / Eclipse

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-spark

I see that from 2.0 onwards spark doesn't come with assembly jar in `/lib` folder. Which jar files do i need to import to use spark in Intellij?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to import maven repository of spark, like this for sbt in build.sbt file

`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "2.0.0"`

same can be found on following link for maven, gradle etc
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10/2.0.0

Comment: after that please refresh it, and it will automatically download all libraries